# How to find record from repository in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I find a record from a repository in the controller? It only search by id but i want to search by email or anything i want?

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('HomeBundle:user')->find($email);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `findOneBy(array)` to find single record by email

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('HomeBundle:user')
    ->findOneBy(array('email' = >$email));
```

Comment: damn I was faster still @M Khalid Junaid gets the accepted answer :(

Answer (score 3):

why not use findOneBy ?

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository('HomeBundle:user')
->findBy(array('email' => $email));
```

Answer (score 1):

For simple queries (basically `WHERE column = value`), you can use `findBy` or `findOneBy`.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entity = $em->getRepository('HomeBundle:user')
             ->findOneBy(array("email"=>$email),array());
$entities = $em->getRepository('HomeBundle:user')
               ->findBy(array("email"=>$email), array());
```

If you need more complex (like `>=` or joins) you can use [query builder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-using-doctrine-s-query-builder) or [dql](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-with-dql).

**But** you should create a [**Custom Repository**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) and put your queries there to make them reusable and keep your controller slim.

This involves the following four steps:

- Creating a UserRepository class with namespace in HomeBundle/Entity extending `EntityRepository`
- Linking your repository in your entity configuration (annotations, yaml or xml)
- Writing repository functions using dql or query builder.
- Calling the repository function instead of `findOneBy`